# Cannot get vlc to work in 17.10

Tags: vlc

```
j@j-samsung:~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
+[000055e800aae9d8] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. >Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[000055e800bc5188] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider >found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[000055e800bc5188] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs >provider
[000055e800bc5188] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for he
```